# How prove this sum indentity with the zeta function and divisor functions

Tags: number-theory

> show that
>   $$\zeta{(s)}\zeta{(s-a)}\zeta{(s-b)}\zeta{(s-c)}\zeta{(s-a-b)}\zeta{(s-b-c)}\zeta{(s-a-c)}\zeta{(s-a-b-c)}
> =\zeta{(3s-a-b-c)}\zeta{(2s-a-b)}\zeta{(2s-b-c)}\zeta{(2s-c-a)}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\sigma_{a}{(n)}\sigma_{b}{(n)}\sigma_{c}(n)}{n}$$

My idea:LHS=$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^s}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{n^a}{n^s}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{n^b}{n^s}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{n^c}{n^s}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{n^{a+b}}{n^s}\sum_{n-1}^{\infty}\dfrac{n^{b+c}}{n^s}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{n^{c+a}}{n^s}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{n^{a+b+c}}{n^s}$$

where
$$\sigma_{N}=\sum_{d|N}d$$

I  know two 
$$\sum_{0<k<n}\sigma{(n-k)}\sigma{(k)}=\dfrac{5\sigma_{3}{(n)}-(6n-1)\sigma{(n)}}{12}$$

maybe this sum is   Ramanujan? But I can't find it on his notebook